# Haskell mapM_ does not print

Tags: haskell, monads

So I wrote a program to query a forex API (foreign exchange), and it works like a charm, but when I want to query every currency pair available, it evaluates all API calls as it takes a long time to execute but prints nothing.

```hs
import Data.Functor ((<&>))

supportedPairs :: IO (Maybe [(String, String)])
forex :: String -> String -> IO (Maybe (Scientific, UnixTime))


main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- supportedPairs
    mapM_ (flip (<&>) print . uncurry forex) (fromJust x)
    -- this prints nothing at all
```

The single calls work just fine like this:

```hs
main = do
    x <- supportedPairs    
    u <- (uncurry forex . (flip (!!) 10 . fromJust)) x
    print u
    -- this prints "Just (438.685041,UnixTime {utSeconds = 1649588583, utMicroSeconds = 0})"
```

Why doesn't the `mapM_` print the results although they are evaluated? If I understood Haskell's laziness correctly, then if the results are not to be printed they should not be evaluated in the first place?

Comment: chi explains it just right, but I should note that `flip (<&>)` is normally spelled `fmap`. You should also check out the `(<$>)` operator.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that!
I guess that's what happens when you try to learn Haskell from scratch :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the types:

`print` is `... -> IO ()`.

Therefore, `... <&> print` is `IO (IO ())`. Note the double IO here.

Hence, mapping over that, will run the "outermost IO" but not the "innermost IO". More concretely, compare this:

```
main = do
  x <- print True >> return 5          -- x is 5
  y <- return (print True >> return 5) -- y is an IO action
  ...
```

Only the first `print True` here is executed: the second IO action is used to define `y` but until we run `y` it won't be executed.

The final point: here, you do not need `<&>` since that creates the nested IO's. Use `flip (>>=) print` (or `(=<<) print`, or `(>>= print)`) instead of `flip <&> print`.

Comment: The `fromJust` would be good to address as well.